# PHP. Нужно организовать проверку внутри вывода

Tags: php

Внутри вывода(echo) необходимо выполнить скрипт, выводится ошибка, помогите пожалуйста с синтаксисом

```
if ($n!=$myrow4['liga'])

echo "

<strong>".$myrow4['para']."</strong>

<span style='padding-top: 4px; font-size: 14px; color: #409E30;'>
  <strong>".$myrow4['stet']."</strong></span><br>
  <span style='padding-left: 4px; font-size: 11px;'>
  "    if 
   ($myrow4['vremya']!='')
                            вывести {".$myrow4['vremya']."} 
иначе вывести {".$myrow4['natalo']."}"
   </span>
</td>

";
```

такой вариант не подходит ->  `if ($myrow4['vremya']!='')  echo "";`

Comment: Для начала оформите код

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Начало".empty($myrow4['vremya'])?$myrow4['natalo']:$myrow4['vremya']."конец";
```

Comment: Тернарный оператор тут весьма кстати

Answer (score 0):

```
echo !empty($myrow4['vremya']) ? $myrow4['vremya'] : '...';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($n!=$myrow4['liga'])
echo ("
<strong>".$myrow4['para']."</strong>
<span style='padding-top: 4px; font-size: 14px; color: #409E30;'>
  <strong>".$myrow4['stet']."</strong></span><br>
  <span style='padding-left: 4px; font-size: 11px;'>");

if ($myrow4['vremya']!='') echo ("".$myrow4['vremya']."");

else echo("".$myrow4['natalo']."");
```

Вот как то так)

Comment: ну ТС в вопросе еще написал, что так не подходит :)